# Batch to make directory with subdirectories from files names

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy, subdirectory

I'm looking for batch to make directory with subdirectories from files names and copy files with the same names to direct directory.
I have multiple files with names like :032557.txt ,032557.csv, 032557.log , 054784.csv , 054784.txt, 054784.log etc. I have batch which makes directory with name from file and copy all files with the same names to content directory. In result I have directory 054784 with file 054784.csv, 054784.txt, 054784.log. I need in result directory 054784 with subdirectories: CSV (where I need file 054784.csv) , TXT (where I need file 054784.txt) and LOG (where I need file 054784.log) etc.

```
@echo off 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do ( 
  if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" ( 
    md "%%~na" 2>nul 
    if exist "%%a" move "%%~na.*" "%%~na" 
  ) 
)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%%~xa will give the extension of the file. The only slightly tricky bit is elimination of the leading dot from the extension.

All of the following are untested. They should work unless I have some silly bugs.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*) do (
  if not "%%~fA"=="%~f0" (
    set "ext=%%~xA"
    if defined ext set "ext=!ext:~1!"
    md "%%~dpnA\!ext!" 2>nul
    move "%%A" "%%~dpnA\!ext!"
  )
)
```

If a file name might contain `!` or `^` then the above will not work because delayed expansion will corrupt the expansion of %%A. The following variation will solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*) do (
  if not "%%~fA"=="%~f0" (
    set "ext=%%~xA"
    set "proj=%%~dpnA"
    set "file=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if defined ext set "ext=!ext:~1!"
    md "!proj!\!ext!" 2>nul
    move "!file!" "!proj!\!ext!"
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Alternatively you could use this to get around the `!` and `^` problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*) do if not "%%~fA"=="%~f0" call :moveFile "%%~fA"
exit /b

:moveFile
set "ext=%~x1"
if defined ext set "ext=%ext:~1%"
md "%~dpn1\%ext%" 2>nul
move %1 "%~dpn1\%ext%"
exit /b
```

Comment: @ dbenham: This works great but sometimes I need some changees. How to switch the code when file extension is different than wanted subdirectory title ? For example when I want 054784.csv in other subdirectory "PHOTO", 032557.log  in "DATA", 032557.txt IN "PATH" or something like this

Comment: @ dbenham : Simply I need to move files with specified by me extension to specified by me subdirectory.